# Is it possible to get ie to render a document as html with an extension that is not .htm or .html? (Windows)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, vbscript, file-extension

I am trying to get an html document that's saved on the file system to run through a vbscript first (to check for script injection) and then open in Internet Explorer if the check passes. I have written the vbscript as well as a .bat to call the script, and all of this works when I don't change the file extension (.htm or .html) but do "open with..." and select my .bat file - the vbscript opens it in IE. But when I change the file extension, IE automatically opens the download dialog instead of rendering the html. I want to use a custom extension as a way of only running certain html docs through my script.

So my question is: Is there a way to get Internet Explorer to recognize and render the document in a file with a custom extension?

Comment: Look in to the MIME type. See `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME`.

Comment: What is the content of the file? Is it actual HTML file or you rename the .bat file as a HTML file? If possible then try to share the sample file that can able to produce the issue on our side. We will try to make a test with and try to produce the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT it is an HTML file. I changed the original file extension type (.htm) to something else so that I could associate this different extension type with my .bat file, which calls the vbs script. The .bat file and the .vbs files are windows batch and visual basic files, respectively.

Comment: Can you inform us what's that custom extension? If it not recognized by IE than it can give you the option to download the file and view it in supported application.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT the extension is .sdoc. But rather than showing the download option, I want IE to read the HTML in this file (it is just an HTML file with the extension changed) and render it as HTML.

Comment: I try to search in the documentation of IE to find a way to render custom extension file in IE but I did not get any way to the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CatCat's comment about setting the MIME type is the right answer